# Getting layers according to the lat long of the area from geoserver

Tags: javascript, maps, geoserver

I am creating an application using google maps and geoserver. I am overlaying the layers as png on google map. Now what I am trying to do is getting the layers info according to lat long of the location.

1. Is it possible to get layers info from geoserver using lat long of the location?
2. Is it possible that we can show vector tiles from geoserver on google maps?

For point 1

bbox

```
{
  minx: 72.24619317700001,
  miny: -67.013055426,
  maxx: 167.97283888699997,
  maxy: -9.799550450000027
}

if( bb.minx <= body.lat && body.lat <= bb.maxx && bb.miny <= body.lng && body.lng <= bb.maxy ) {
                existingLayers.push(layer.title);
            }
```

This did't worked

Comment: Do you mean you want a list of layers that cover a point?

Comment: yes, like I have circle of radius x, so I want to check which layers  comes under that radius from geoserver list of layers

Answer (score 0):

for your first question: you need to fetch the servers getCapabilities document and then each layer will have a bounding box element. Then you just need to iterate through the layer elements and check if your point is within the bounds of the layer.

Comment: {
  minx: 72.24619317700001,
  miny: -67.013055426,
  maxx: 167.97283888699997,
  maxy: -9.799550450000027
}

if( bb.minx <= body.lat && body.lat <= bb.maxx && bb.miny <= body.lng && body.lng <= bb.maxy ) {
                existingLayers.push(layer.title);
            }
did't worked